# Java Console Pushes Input Text When Logging Occurs

Tags: java, shell, logging, input

Through [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)'s SSH feature, I'm running a Java application on a remote Linux server. A problem arises when I attempt to type into the terminal (to process user input requests via [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)) and any logging occurs. The text I'm typing is automatically pushed into the logging section when any print statements happen.

Clarifying example:

1. I manually type **"MY_INPUT_TO_SET_SOME_VARIABLE 50"** into the console (and never press ENTER).

   [image]
2. Some logging on the server occurs and automatically "sends" the manually typed **"MY_INPUT_TO_SET_SOME_VARIABLE 50"** into the display area.

   [image]

   (above, you can see **50** is appended to **09:08** when I never pressed enter).

The desired behavior is to allow the power user to simply type text in the terminal's text area (or somewhere reasonable) until the ENTER key is pressed. The text in the terminal's text area should not automatically be pushed upon logged or printed statements. I looked in terminal settings and wasn't able to find anything to modify this behavior.

Comment: Looks like a normal behavior. Both you prompt and the log are printed to the standard out, there's nothing to tell it to block (essentially buffering some data) until a user presses Enter. Did you try running something similar locally?

Comment: I did test it locally, and this does appear to be "normal behavior" - the text I'm typing is always appended to the larger text area upon any incoming logging. Is it not possible to separate my input text from the logging big text area? .. say, always having whatever I'm typing on a new line and remaining there until I press ENTER? see (http://puu.sh/wY6Dp/acafce9e18.png) and (http://puu.sh/wY6Hh/34dfdb4de4.png) for clarification.

Comment: Initially console aka terminal was designed around the "stream" concept because this is what the original terminals did: they just printed a stream of characters. Under the "stream" concept you can separate several streams and print them differently. But if you mix them into a single output, you can't hold a position in just one of them. When display-based terminals appeared, text-based UI abilities were added such as [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) but this is an advanced feature which typically requires an explicit support from the application even for such a simple feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others already mentioned in the comment section there is not much you can do about that behaviour.

However usually you don't want logging on the [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) you're working with.

If you have root rights on the system you connect to try to suppress the log  messages on the console and redirect them to a logfile unless there is a good reason not to do so. Since it depends who is sending the messages the method to do so differs.

Another possibility is to start a [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) session in your terminal to open a new tty.
For ease of use I would connect directly into a screen session:

```
ssh -t user@server /usr/bin/screen
```

If you create a .screenrc file in the home directory of the user you connect to, put

```
startup_message off
```

in it if you don't like the screen start message. You can even start your console app with it, so that the screen session ends when you stop your app.

```
ssh -t user@server /usr/bin/screen your_start_command_here
```

Screen has more features like naming a session, reattaching to a session etc. See the manual for further details.

(The screen solution apparently only works if the log messages on the screen are not produced by your application. In that case configure your logger that it does not log to stdout)